# Display an element when hover on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display the element `#b` when the user hovers on `#a`. On page load `#b` will be set to `display: none`.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="a">Suite</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <img id="b" src="img/image.png">
  </div> 
</div>
```

```css
#b { display: none; }
#a:hover #b { display: block; } /* Not Working */
#a:hover > #b { display: block; } /* Not Working */
#a:hover + #b { display: block; } /* Not Working */
#a:hover ~ #b { display: block; } /* Not Working */
```

I have tried many methods but none worked. This is a very simple thing, and it's not happening. Please help.

Comment: CSS is exactly as it states: **Cascading** Style Sheets. The implication is that you cannot pass styles "upwards" to parent elements or unrelated elements, but instead only to descendants and siblings. You can't achieve your desired effect without some JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want to hide `#b` on mouseout?

Comment: Here is an example of pure css working, with the requirement that `#b` is a child of `#a`: https://jsfiddle.net/ot7z9by9/

Comment: You have several answers here. Please either choose one, or comment on why they do not fit your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot achieve what you require in CSS alone as the HTML structure is too convoluted. The `#b` element would need to be a sibling or child of the `#a` element.

If you cannot amend the HTML you would need to use JS instead:

```js
$('#a').hover(function() {
  $('#b').toggle();
});
```

```css
#b { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="a">Suite</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <img id="b" src="img/image.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. One more thing I have multiple <li>. So I have used following js. Can I use a compact JS? <code>$('#ldp-1').hover(function() {
  $('#ldi-1').toggle();
  $('#ldi-1-wp').toggle();
  $('#ldi-1-si').toggle();
  $('#ldi-1-dc').toggle();
});
$('#ldp-2').hover(function() {
  $('#ldi-2').toggle();
  $('#ldi-2-wp').toggle();
  $('#ldi-2-si').toggle();
  $('#ldi-2-dc').toggle();
});</code> and so on

Comment: While that would work, the code would become needlessly long and a pain to maintain. Instead you could use common classes and join the elements by index: https://jsfiddle.net/dr7yx6a5/

Answer (score 1):

Toggle a class that shows the hidden element on the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

```js
var a = document.getElementById('a'),
    b = document.getElementById('b');

a.addEventListener('mouseover',function() {
  b.classList.add('show');
});

a.addEventListener('mouseout',function() {
  b.classList.remove('show');
});
```

```css
#b {
  display: none;
}
#b.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="a">Suite</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <img id="b" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but only on the `hover` of the container of `#a`, because it has to be a sibling of the container of `#b`.

here I have moved the `id="a"` up to the same level as the container of `#b`, and then the selector is as simple as `#a:hover + div #b`.

```css
#b {
  display: none;
}

#a:hover + div #b {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <ul>
    <li>Suite</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <img id="b" src="img/image.png">
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With  your current HTML this is going to be the only way.

```js
document.querySelector("#a").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.querySelector("#b").classList.add("show");
});

document.querySelector("#a").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  document.querySelector("#b").classList.remove("show");
});
```

```css
#b {
  display: none;
}

#b.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="a">Suite</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <img id="b" src="http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-13.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't mind changing your HTML, you could go for something like

```css
li span+img {
  display: none;
}

li span:hover+img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Hover</span>
      <img src="http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-13.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Want to show id element of a div B when Hover on id element of div A [..] I have tried many methods on the internet but none worked. This is a very simple thing, and its not happening. Please help.

Here is a vanilla JavaScript example. Hope this helps.

**Example:**

```
var divA = document.getElementById('a');
var divB = document.getElementById('b');

divA.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    divB.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Made a CodePen demo for you, adapted to your html example. Complete with a unicorn, a cat, and rainbows.

**CodePen Demo (unicorn inside):**

http://codepen.io/robee/pen/EWKZjz